# Updating Query in Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am new to Firestore, need some help on firestore update.

I have following structure and wants to update "employee name" property. Not sure how to select and update.

```
Department:[
  Name: Accounts
  Employee:[ 
    {Name :David,
   Age :25},
   {Name:Paul,
   Age:27}
 ]
]
```

Here is what I was trying to do:

```
let depempCollectionRef = admin.firestore().collection('DepEmployee').doc('depempid') 
depempCollectionRef.Department.Employee
  .update({ name: 'Scott' },{merge:true})
  .then(function() { console.log("Document successfully updated!"); })
```

Comment: Here is what I was trying to do:                                                                         let depempCollectionRef = admin.firestore().collection('DepEmployee').doc('depempid')
depempCollectionRef.Department.Employee
.update({        
           name: 'Scott'
           },{merge:true})
           .then(function() {
             console.log("Document successfully updated!");
        })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Employee` is just an embedded data structure in your Firestore document – so you can't address it through the reference directly. As far as Firestore is concerned, `Employee` is just an attribute on the `Department` document as `Name` is.

Before I propose a solution, let me point out two things:

1. If using `update`, you don't need `{merge: true}`. You use `{merge: true}` together with `set` to get an update-like behavior, if the document already exists.
2. I wouldn't use an `Array` of employees. It might make more sense to store the employees in their own collection in Firestore and then just list their reference IDs (= foreign keys) here. As a general rule of thumb: try to keep your data structure flat. Also use `Arrays` only, if you need to maintain a certain order of items.

**A)** If you have a separate collection for employees, updating the name is as easy as:

`employeeCollection.doc('101').update({name: 'Scott'})`

**B)** If you want to store employee data within your department document, I would still store them as a map with IDs (instead of an `Array`) and then access them with dot notation:

```
Department:[
  Name: Accounts
  Employees:{ 
    101: {
      Name :David,
      Age :25
    },
    102: {
      Name:Paul,
      Age:27
    }
  }
]

depempCollectionRef.Department
  .set({ ['101.name']: 'Scott' }, {merge:true})
```

**C)** And if you really want to store the data embedded in an `Array`, I believe you have to read and update the whole `Array` (not sure, if there is a better solution):

```
const employeesSnap = await depempCollectionRef.Department.get()
const updatedEmployees = changeNameOfScottInArray()
depempCollectionRef.Department
  .update({ 'Employees': updatedEmployees })
```

I didn't test this code, but I hope you get the gist of it!

I'd recommend you flatten your data structure by creating a separate `Employee` collection and then just referencing them by their foreign key in your department (solution A).